# How to sum of values in dict? Python, Flask

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

I have simple shopping cart created via session in Flask:

```
session['cart'] += [{
    'product_name': request.form['product_name'],
    'product_cost': request.form['product_cost'],
    'product_img': request.form['product_img'],
}]
```

So how can get sum of values in `product_cost`?

I tried do that to get value of `product_cost`:

```
for products in cart_products:
    for p in products:
        print(p.product_cost)
```

But I get an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'product_cost'`

Output of `print(cart_products)`, where `cart_products = session['cart']`:

```
{'product_name': 'product2', 'product_cost': '400', 'product_img': '*very long binary object*'}
```

Comment: Showing how you build `session['cart']` is no use, as nobody knows what the submitted values will look like.  If you're assigning that to `cart_products`, you'd be better showing the output of `print(cart_products)` so we can actually see the datastructure you are trying to process.

Comment: @v25 Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your edit, note that this is actually a dictionary:

```
product_cart = {'product_name': 'product2', 'product_cost': '400', 'product_img': ''}
```

So the cost is accessible via `product_cart['product_cost']`.

However I'm not sure if you really mean to maintain this as a list of dictionaries (where the list is the cart contents, and each dictionary is a product.  That would look like:

```
product_cart = [{'product_name': 'product1', 'product_cost': '300', 'product_img': ''},
                {'product_name': 'product2', 'product_cost': '400', 'product_img': ''},
                {'product_name': 'product3', 'product_cost': '300', 'product_img': ''},
                ]
```

You could then do:

```
>>> for product in product_cart:
...  print (product['product_cost'])
... 
300
400
300
```

So to get the some of all the values, have a function like:

```
def get_cart_total(cart):
     return sum([float(product['product_cost']) for product in cart ])
```

Note this turns the string values like '400' to type `float`.  Use it like:

```
>>> get_cart_total(product_cart)
1000.0
```

Comment: I tried this on my other PC now and I got `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. Considering u said that string values converts to float

Comment: @h4cktivist not sure if this is related to be honest.  I suggest logging a separate question with a minimal example of the current code which triggers that Exception, and the full traceback so people can see where in the code this goes wrong.

Comment: I asked I new question here, maybe u can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980581/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-python-flask

Answer (score 0):

Using the first for loop you are accessing the dictionaries but the problem is, you are accessing the keys inside the dictionary instead of the values using the second for loop.
So instead just do this:

```
for products in cart_products:
    print(products['product_cost'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum of `product_cost` you would need:

```
 sum([int(x['product_cost']) for x in session['cart']])
```

Example:

```
cart = [
    {
        'product_name': 'abc',
        'product_cost': 12,
        'product_img': 'abc.jpg',
    },
    {
        'product_name': 'abc',
        'product_cost': 13,
        'product_img': 'abc.jpg',
    },
    {
        'product_name': 'abc',
        'product_cost': 14,
        'product_img': 'abc.jpg',
    },
]

total = sum([x['product_cost'] for x in cart])
print(total)
```

->

```
39
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
some_var = session[‘cart’][0].values()
another_var = len(some_var)
```