# TypeError: string indices must be integers. Python, Flask

Tags: python

I have a simple cart created via session in Flask:

```
session['cart'] += [{
    'product_name': request.form['product_name'],
    'product_cost': request.form['product_cost'],
    'product_img': request.form['product_img'],
}]
```

Example of cart:

```
product_cart = [{'product_name': 'product1', 'product_cost': '300', 'product_img': ''},
                {'product_name': 'product2', 'product_cost': '400', 'product_img': ''},
                {'product_name': 'product3', 'product_cost': '300', 'product_img': ''},
               ]
```

Where `product_cart = session['cart']`

I need to get sum of `product_cost` values. I tried to do this that way:

`sum([int(product['product_cost']) for product in product_cart ])`

But a got this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. As I untestand, `product_cost` shouild be `int` type instead of `str` as in dict. But I already converted it into `int` when I tried to get sum of them (see code higher).

So, what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix this error? Thanks!

Edit:

`print(session['cart']`:

`[{'product_name': 'product1', 'product_cost': '300', 'product_img': '*binary img*'}, {'product_name': 'product2', 'product_cost': '400', 'product_img': '*binary img*'}]`

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-   packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\jewelry-store\app.py", line 336, in cart
full_cost = sum([int(product['product_cost']) for product in cart_products ])
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\jewelry-store\app.py", line 336, in <listcomp>
full_cost = sum([int(product['product_cost']) for product in cart_products ])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: could you print value of `session['cart']` and add it to your question text please?

Comment: According to the error you got, `product` is a string and you should convert it to `dict` first.

Comment: @Gabip So, how can I do that?

Comment: Could you share the result of `print(type(session['cart']))`? Just to make sure that my guess is correct

Comment: @Gabip `<class 'list'>`

Comment: And the elements inside your `session['cart']` are dicts?

Comment: @Gabip I think so

Comment: Please check it using `type` function as well

Comment: @Gabip And how can i do that?

Comment: you can loop over `session['cart']` and print the type of each element.

Comment: Can you post the full trackback (not just the last line which is the exception) so we can actually see where this fails.

Comment: @Gabip there're a lot of `<class 'dict'>`

Comment: @v25 Edited traceback

Comment: Your summing code works perfectly well for both carts shown (your example and the one printed out). Either your code is different (perhaps `cart_products` is different than `product_cart`?) or the error is occurring when called on a different cart than the shown examples. As Gabip has already observed, somehow one or more of the items in your cart is a string instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Please provide a clear [mre]. Running your line of `sum` with the provided `product_cart` didn't raise any errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something doesn't add up (no pun intended) here:

```
full_cost = sum([int(product['product_cost']) for product in cart_products ])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When the `product_cart` in your question is supplied as the input to this it should work.

However if you had a string as a member of the `product_cart` list, instead of a dictionary it would throw this exception:

```
>>> product_cart = ['test']
>>> sum([int(product['product_cost']) for product in product_cart ])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Or to put it another way:

```
>>> {'product_cost':'123'}['product_cost']
'123'
>>> 'some_string'['product_cost']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

So the exception you're seeing in your code is because the list comprehension within the sum function, is getting a string for `product`.

Something is not as it seems within your `session['cart']` so it's impossible for anyone to solve with the info given in this question, sorry.

Comment: Yes, exaclty, I just recreated session and it works. Sorry for waste ur time

Comment: @h4cktivist no waste, glad you got to the bottom of it, and hope this answer helped you understand why.  Also i suggest using `float` instead of `int` because **if** you have a cost string in your cart, which contains a decimal it will throw an exception.  Eg... `int('1.2')` gives `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.2'`.